# kube-prometheus-stack Upgrade Prometheus Version

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I installed kube-prometheus-stack in [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack). I noticed the Prometheus has the version of 1.7. I am wondering how can I upgrade it to 2.0or up?

I used `helm install latest prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack` to install kube-prometheus-stack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your chart repository is not updated.

Update your chart repo:

```
$ helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts

$ helm repo update
```

Varify:

```sh
$ helm search repo prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
NAME                                        CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION                                       
prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack  11.0.0          0.43.0      kube-prometheus-stack collects Kubernetes manif...
```

Now try installing again:

```
$ helm install latest prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

You will have Prometheus of version `v2.22.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for the Prometheus version used in the `kube-prometheus-stack` Helm chart is v2.22.0, as you can see [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/3ab7f9b04e1ab5abd6c0b35268368422436ae3a6/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L1633).

So, you don't need to do anything special to get Prometheus 2+. If you get Prometheus 1.7, this value is most probably overwritten in your `values.yaml` file.